# Does PostgreSQL support rounding at the database level?

Tags: postgresql

For example is it possible to ensure that a particular number field is always rounded to exactly three decimal places?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Define the column as `DECIMAL(16, 3)` - see [the postgres documentation for this type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL)

The first number (16 in this case) is the maximum *total* number of digits in the number, the second number (3 in this case) is the number of decimal places.

Every database (I know of) supports this datatype.

Comment: True. The storage and performance however are different from those of floating point. It is the old friend BCD, computed afaik on the primary cpu. (PG manual states "The actual storage requirement is two bytes for each group of four decimal digits, plus three to eight bytes overhead". More here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-numeric.html)